# How to stop an SQL query when browser is closed

Tags: java, .net, sql-server

I really can't find decent documentation for a problem that (I think) is quite general.

If I have a website written in .Net or Java which allows for users to execute very high demanding SQL queries against a DB (MS SQL) what is the best way to ensure that these queries are being killed/stopped if the user leaves the page or closes the browser before the reply is being returned.

I got the part that using a Javascript you can ping the server from the webpage to make sure that the client is still on, but then how do you link that to the specific query and kill it (e.g. if the user moves from one page to another the ping will still work, but the sql query should be stopped)

Comment: When the JavaScript stops calling home for a specified period of time, cancel the query.  Anything beyond that is language dependent, and framework dependent.  You would really need to post what you have tried, and why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ["window.onbeforeunload"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload) event to fire off a notification to the server when the user leaves.

Comment: does this get fired if the browser crashes?

Comment: @tieTYT the whole point of crashing is that it is an 'unexpected painful and definitive shutdown'. If the browser still knew how to send JS events for all its tabs it wouldn't be crashing.